# Android Lollipop button to change interruption filter

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a dialog that pops up and has a button. I want the button to change the interruption filter (None, Priority, All) every time it is clicked. When I click the button the notification mode does not change and the console says Notification listener service not yet bound. I have the app enabled in notification access settings. What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to change the notification mode?

`myDialog.java` in `onCreate()`:

```
final NotificationService notifs = new NotificationService();
getContext().bindService(new Intent(getContext(), NotificationService.class), new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }
}, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
getContext().startService(new Intent(getContext(), NotificationService.class));

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(notifs.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == NotificationListenerService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE){
            //set all
            button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), volume));
            notifs.requestInterruptionFilter(NotificationService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
        } else if(notifs.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == NotificationService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY) {
            //set none
            button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), none));
            notifs.requestInterruptionFilter(NotificationService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
        } else {
            //set priority
            button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), priority));
            notifs.requestInterruptionFilter(NotificationService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
        }
    }
});
```

`NotificationService.java`:

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    public NotificationService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("NOTIF", "Started");
    }
}
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am i doing wrong?

`NotificationListenerService` is a `Service`. Hence, you do not create anonymous inner class implementations of `NotificationListenerService`. Instead, you create a regular `public` Java class for it and register it in the manifest, as shown in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). This service will be automatically set up by Android, if and only if the user elects to enable your app to listen to notifications, by going into Settings and enabling it.

Comment: I edited my question to the code I have now, but it still gives the same error. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @yawers: Well, you still have all the broken code in "myDialog.java in onCreate()". Adding more code will not cause broken code to become unbroken, in most cases. Start by deleting all of that. Then, add some stuff to your `NotificationService` and enable it in Settings to see if you have the basic service working. Then, and only then, worry about how you are going to communicate from your UI layer to that service, how that service will persist its data across reboots, etc.

Comment: I deleted the previous code, what is shown above is all I have now. I have it enabled in settings and it does start, but it still does not change the interruption filter, and still says `Notification listener service not yet bound`. Is there something wrong with they way I am calling it? What else should I add to `NotificationService.java`?

Comment: @yawers: You are attempting to create an instance of your service yourself. That is not how [services work](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Put this project aside for a while. Start with a simpler app, but one that involves a service. Learn how to work with services properly. Then, and only then, return to this project, and apply what you learned to working with your `NotificationListenerService`, noting that you cannot do notification-related work in that service until Android has set up the service for you, based on the user requesting it in Settings.